# Vue warn: cannot find element :#historicalFigures

Tags: javascript, vue.js

*Help please i dont know how to solve this and im new to vue.js
The error is as below:
[Vue warn]Cannot find element:#historicalFigures
[Vue warn]You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
*[Vue warn]: option "el" can only be used during instance creation with the `new` keyword.*
    found in
    ---> 
    UserName
    HistoricalFigures at src/components/HistoricalFigures.vue
    App at src/App.vue
    Root vue.runtime.esm.js:619*

this is the code in HistoricalFigures.vue and im using visual studio code to do this

```
<template>
<div id="historicalFigures">
    <img src="@/assets/blockChain.jpg"/>
    <h2> The philosopher socrates born in greece had implanted primordial idea of free speech politics to the people that time</h2>
    <user-name name="Flavio"></user-name>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('user-name', {
props: ['name'],
template: '<p>Hi {{ name }}</p>'
})


export default {    
el:'#historicalFigures'
}
</script>
```

and this is the content of App.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<body>

<ul class="sidenav">
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><router-link to="graphView">Graph View</router-link></li>
<li><router-link to="historicalFigures">Historical Figures</router-link> </li>
</ul>

   <div class="content"> 
   <router-view/>

  </div>

  </body>

 </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import { ButtonPlugin } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-buttons';
 import { enableRipple } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';

enableRipple(true);
Vue.use(ButtonPlugin);


export default {
name: 'App',
methods : {
    btnClick: function() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com");
    },
    btnCalculate: function() {
        alert('Hello ' + 1+2 + '!')
    }
  }
 }


</script>

<style>
 #app {
 font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2c3e50;
 margin-top: 60px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: If you're using webpack, you need to update your vue alias to use the correct build: https://gist.github.com/anchal20/f2ac9807263e106c1308f7143df1cf09

Comment: historicalFigures is created by a component that renders to historicalFigures. It's a catch-22.

Comment: am i creating a component inside a component thats why it doenst work lol?

Comment: Your SFC doesn't need to specify `el` since the provided `template` is used. The solution is to simply remove the `el` property.

Comment: As an aside, it's also unusual to declare a global component from an SFC (i.e., via `Vue.component`). Global components should be done in another file, such as `main.js` or a related file. Instead of a global component, I would move the `user-name` definition into its own SFC.